# Why don't we have to use "frame" when declaring a custom view?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I don't get why when I create this view:

```
class MenuBar: UIView {
    override init (frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

...and when I using it in another class, I can put some code like this:

```
let menuBar: MenuBar = {
    let mb = MenuBar()
    return mb
}()
```

Why don't I have to mention anything about `frame`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIView` has a **default initializer** which has **no arguments**. Regardless of subclassing `UIView` or not, that initializer is available. It initalizes a `UIView` instance with a frame of `CGRect.zero`.

Comment: cause it's inherits from nsobject?

Answer (score 3):

You are calling a convenience initializer inherited from the `UIView` implementation. This parameterless convenience initializer calls the one with the frame and passes it a default value - in the end, your initializer with `frame` is called from the inherited superclass initializer.

Comment: but then where does it find this frame?

Comment: It will automatically use CGRect.zero.